# Is there a way to add or change Android apps language after packaging it into an APK?

Tags: android, localization

In the case of a windows application(EXE/DLL), we can change or add language resources within the binary without re-compiling it. Can the same be done in case of an Android application? Is there any editor available to make this happen?

My plan is to develop the application in English and then release it to the sales department, where they will be responsible for the localization of the application without compiling and packaging it into a new APK. I just want to split the development part and localization part of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to localize is to create a string resource for your base language and then have that localized and reimported into your project for every language that you support.

Much more detail can be found in the [Localization documentation.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

I don't believe there is a safe/supported way to inject localized strings into your app after it's been built.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can not, because once your apk is signed then modifying it after this (you can always do that as apk is just a zip file) will corrupt the signed binary.

Answer (score 0):

When having multiple languages with your application you have to build them into the application itself. Android uses XML files to store strings used within your application. Android allows you to add language localization files containing local specific strings. You can't do this without recompiling your project so you'll want to do it as a future update or right from the start. But you can't have the marketing department do it, that's just not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the short answer is no.  The long(er) answer is sort of.  If you pack all your language resources into remote XML that can be updated from the web, then with a little bit of forethought you can do all sorts of live updates to your app's strings, graphics, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to use the standard R.string method for everything it will be a little difficult. I think it's possible to do something funky with a dynamic classloader for the assets and static dex classes (basically classes of data with just inline byte arrays that can be decoded after). However that would still require compiling. See [Custom Class Loading in Dalvik](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html) for more info.

Another approach would be more of a standard Java implementation. Java has a class known as ResourceBundle. You could create a [ResourceBundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) from a property file (key-value plain text, or even property xml). Then these files could be loaded outside the apk, via a network connection or sdcard or other file type resource and deleted as necessary. You will have to write the loader code for it, but that's going to happen with any solution. This solution will be less performant and outside the standard design methods for android but it will solve the problem being asked to solve. Like you won't be able to use R.string or @string/whatever for any of these resources but I think you may be able to write an adapter to such resources (like your own TextView extension and whatever that would allow all of this). It's a matter mostly of how much work you want to invest in solving this actual problem.

Honestly I would opt for trying to distribute whole apks with only the targeted language if you are trying to save space, but then there is no way to change locale for the app at runtime :(